# how to sync the perforce client to a particular change list using p4 sync command

Tags: perforce

let us assume depot contains change lists :

change lists :
300
299
280
270
260

I would like to sync my client at change list 280.

if i do p4 sync : my client will be updated with cl : 300 (latest one) which i'm not looking for.

How can we achieve this ?

Answer (score 36):

Perforce uses "@" to indicate change number,  so

```
p4 sync @280
```

Comment: How do we confirm that we are on that change number once we execute the command?

Comment: @user3303020 you can try using `p4 changes -m 1 //...#have` it will show the changelist number along with short description for local workspace you're on.

Comment: Whats the difference between 
```p4 sync @280``` and 
```p4 sync ... @280```

Comment: @user3303020 `...` is the path. There's no difference between the two but you can use it to specify a subpath - `dir/...` for example, which will only sync that directory.

Answer (score 0):

`p4 sync ...@280`

Accepted answer didn't work for me

To check latest synced CL: `p4 changes -m1 //...#have`

Comment: Shouldn't it be `//...@280` ? If you're in the client root directory, then what you have should work, but if you're not, best provide the full spec.